# Azure worker role accessing web role configuration file

Tags: azure

I have a cloud service with a WebRole and a WorkerRole. Within the WebRole, I have 9 different deployment configurations, each with their own connection strings. These connection strings are encrypted.

For ease of use, I have created a function in this WebRole that will return the connection string from the web.config.

Within the WorkerRole, I have added a reference to the WebRole dll. I can then call the function above to get the connection string for the deployment configuration I need.

This worked perfectly for about a month. Then it stopped working, and is always returning the development connection string. I don't understand why it would work for a while, and then stop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your configurations are in the .cscfg file?  If yes, then you deployed a .cscfg file with the development connection strings in the WorkerRole's configuration section.  You can see the configuration values in the management portal to verify this.